# Connection mongo with python

Tags: python, mongodb, mlab

I'm trying to connect to a mongo db using python, this is my code:

```
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient

MONGODB_URI = "mongodb://<user_name>:<user_password>@ds035177.mlab.com:35177<something>"
client = MongoClient(MONGODB_URI, connectTimeoutMS=30000)
db = client.get_default_database("<db_default>")
myDB = db.<collection>
record = {
    "user_id" : 1,
    "name" : "test",
    "college" : "test"
}
myDB.insert_one(record)
```

For some reason i'm getting timeout and i dont' know why...

Answer (score 0):

Can you connect from command line on your desktop; e.g.

```
mongo mongodb://<user_name>:<user_password>@ds035177.mlab.com:35177<something>
```

If not, chances are the server isn't running on port 35177,  or port 35177 isn't open, or you haven't allowed external access from the mongo server.